# Properties, Arrays and ArrayLists using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

In my code behind in my Web project I have a Property

```
Public Shared UserAttributes(2) As String
    Public Property _UserAttributes(ByVal Index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return UserAttributes(Index)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            UserAttributes(Index) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And I also have an `ArrayList` declared as `Friend`

```
Friend UserParameters As New ArrayList
```

I call my property like that:

```
_UserAttributes(0) = "parameter1"
_UserAttributes(1) = "parameter2"
_UserAttributes(2) = "parameter3"
UserParameters.Add(UserAttributes)
_UserAttributes(0) = "parameter1,1"
_UserAttributes(1) = "parameter2,1"
_UserAttributes(2) = "parameter3,1"
UserParameters.Add(UserAttributes)
```

From the above code we may see the two pairs of Attributes having one text each one.
What I need now is: 
After I add the three Attributes from my `Property` to my `ArrayList`
The second three Attributes of my property NOT to spoil the first one.
Which by now that they are doing 
And finally I have two(2) `_items` in my `ArrayList` which they have the same text on each `_item` (which is the last one).
What I need is to write the second (or more) set of Attributes without spoiling the previous `_items` from `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've made it to solve this puzzle as follows 
One Property as `ArrayList`

```
Public Property _UserParameters As ArrayList
        Get
            Return UserParameters
        End Get
        Set(value As ArrayList)
            UserParameters = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Second Property as `Array`

```
Public Property _UserAttributes(ByVal Index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return UserAttributes(Index)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            UserAttributes(Index) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And from code behind I use this code:

```
Dim UserAttributes As New Hashtable
    Dim key As Object = Nothing
    Dim Param As Object = Nothing
    Dim myList As New ArrayList
    Dim item As Object = UserAttributes
    UserAttributes.Add("UserId", "Parametr1")
    UserAttributes.Add("UserName", "Parametr2")
    UserAttributes.Add("UserMail", "Parametr3")
    For Each item In UserAttributes
        key = item.Key
        Param = item.value
        logHandler._UserParameters.Add(key & "^" & Param)
    Next
    myList.Add(logHandler.UserParameters.ToArray)
    UserAttributes.Clear()
    logHandler.UserParameters.Clear()
    UserAttributes.Add("UserId", "Parametr1-1")
    UserAttributes.Add("UserName", "Parametr2-1")
    UserAttributes.Add("UserMail", "Parametr3-1")
    For Each item In UserAttributes
        key = item.Key
        Param = item.value
        logHandler._UserParameters.Add(key & "^" & Param)
    Next
    myList.Add(logHandler.UserParameters.ToArray)
```

The use of `HashTable` solves my issue, Along with the conversion from `HashTable` parameters to String 
Which add them first to the `ArrayList` Property
And after that add them to the second `ArrayList`
And the result of these `ArrayList` I add it to a `Pull Down menu` control.
And Why I'm doing all that?
That is because I have many users with the same attributes as keys but deferent values
Good day to all, with many thanks.